# my drag drop functions don't be triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

1. I try to make drag drop in javascrit but i can't trigger my drag
   drop functions. i call these functions in document ready. But i can
   call only when page loads. İ can't trigger my events. Thank you..

This İs My Html

```
 <div id="dropZone"></div>
```

and this is my functions

```
  $(document).ready(function () { 
        var dropZone = document.getElementById('dropZone');
        if (dropZone) {
            dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
            dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
            dropZone.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
        }
    });
    function handleFileSelect(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files; // FileList object.
        uploadTheFile(evt,"new",files);
    }

    function handleDragOver(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'; // Explicitly show this is a copy.
        var $dragOver = $("#dropZone");
        $dragOver.removeClass("article-content-add-new-images");
        $dragOver.addClass("article-content-add-new-images-drag");

    }
    function handleDragLeave(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        var $dragLeave = $("#dropZone");
        $dragLeave.removeClass("article-content-add-new-images-drag");
        $dragLeave.addClass("article-content-add-new-images");

    }
```

Comment: uploadTheFile() is missing that you called in handleFileSelect functiion

Answer (score 0):

Try adding content (e.g. non-breaking space) to your div first because it has a height of 0px now. Not much chance it gets triggered. (Styled red background so it is visible where drops are allowed). I don't see any errors in the code.

```
<div id="dropZone" style="background:red;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle showing the code works as-is.

https://jsfiddle.net/6rw6y9Lf/

[image]

Comment: Actually I didn't write css codes in here so it has width and height.